# How to add pinch Gesture to scale circle drawed by UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, iphone, uibezierpath, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have created circle in my app as bellow

```
UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:bounds];
```

Now problem is that I need to apply pinch gesture to scale in and out circle. I have stucked with this issue. Please give guidance in this issue.